# Need to change phone number

Tags: ipad

When you update to iOS 8 you get asked a bunch of questions one of them is "what phone number to put in" how can I change it?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: The only time I see a phone number on my iPad with any choice to enable or disable is with iMessage. Was that the prompt you are asking about?

Answer (score 1):

I assume these are questions related to your Apple ID. In this case you can point Safari to http://appleid.apple.com/ and update your data there.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Settings** → **Phone** → **My Number** and enter your phone number.